# Selecting a random record in SQLite from records that have a specific value to a column

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am making an application in Android, and I am using SQLite database.

Is it possible for me to select a random record in a table from the records that have a specific value to one of the columns?

Let’s say I have a table called T, which has a set of columns: a, b, c.
Can I select a random record from this table, but ONLY from the records with no null value for the “c” column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes it is possible**, you could use something like :-

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c IS NOT NULL ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

- This utilises the **[random function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random)** to ORDER the result set using the **ORDER BY** clause and then selects just 1 row via the **LIMIT** clause.

*P.S. a, b and c are generally called **columns** rather than **attributes***

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you mean columns when you say attributes. If so, do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE c IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```